# Moving some models to ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have Logging model that related to db table

Here is code:

```
public partial class Logging
{
    public string Imei { get; set; }
    public DateTime CurDateTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> GPSDateTime2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Latitude2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Longitude2 { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Datatype { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

}
```

I want to calculate difference and decided to create ViewModel

Here is code

```
 public class HeatmapViewModel:Logging
{
    public TimeSpan? FirstStartDifference
    {
        get
        {
            if (CurDateTime != null)
            {
                var midnight = new DateTime(CurDateTime.Year, CurDateTime.Month, CurDateTime.Day, 00, 00, 00);
                var difference = CurDateTime - midnight;
                return difference;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    public TimeSpan? LastStartDifference
    {
        get
        {
            if (CurDateTime != null)
            {
                var midnight = new DateTime(CurDateTime.Year, CurDateTime.Month, CurDateTime.Day, 23, 59, 00);
                var difference = midnight - CurDateTime;
                return difference;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    public int coeff = 2;
    public int Difference;
}
```

And on back-end I have this method

```
List<HeatmapViewModel> items = new List<HeatmapViewModel>();

            var firstitem = ctx.Loggings.Where(x => x.Datatype == 2).AsEnumerable().Select(
                x => new HeatmapViewModel
                {
                    Longitude2 = x.Longitude2,
                    Latitude2 = x.Latitude2,
                    Difference = (int)(x.FirstStartDifference?.TotalMinutes ?? -1) * x.coeff

                }).FirstOrDefault();
            var lastItem = ctx.Loggings.Where(x => x.Datatype == 2).AsEnumerable().Select(
                x => new HeatmapViewModel
                {
                    Longitude2 = x.Longitude2,
                    Latitude2 = x.Latitude2,
                    Difference = (int)(x.LastStartDifference?.TotalMinutes ?? -1) * x.coeff

                }).LastOrDefault();
```

But on this row `Difference = (int)(x.FirstStartDifference?.TotalMinutes ?? -1) * x.coeff`, I have error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'Logging' does not contain a definition for 'FirstStartDifference' and no extension method 'FirstStartDifference' accepting a first argument of type 'Logging' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Heatmap C:\Users\nemes\source\repos\Heatmap\Heatmap\Controllers\HomeController.cs   28  Active

How I can use property from VIewModel

Comment: Assuming that Loggings is a collection of instances of type Logging, then you are trying to use a property FirstStartDifference on each logging instance, which doesn't exist.

Comment: You appear to be fetching `Logging` records from your data context, and that first `Logging` class doesn't have that property.  Did you mean for your second `Logging` class to be a `partial class` to extend the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multi-line lambda instead:

```
var firstitem = Loggings.Where(x => x.Datatype == 2).AsEnumerable().Select(
x =>
{
    var vm = new HeatmapViewModel
    {
        Longitude2 = x.Longitude2,
        Latitude2 = x.Latitude2
    };
    vm.Difference = (int)(vm.FirstStartDifference?.TotalMinutes ?? -1) * vm.coeff;
    return vm;
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note: Please read comments below your post, because you are mixing types. Variable `x` is of type `Logging`